# How do I do a proper Compass installation on Windows 7?

Tags: ruby, windows-7, compass-sass

When I run compass from anywhere besides Ruby's bin folder, it comes back with an error:

```
'compass' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Has this happened to anyone else? I read somewhere that maybe there needs to be a file in Windows32, compass.exe maybe, I'm not sure because there's nothing that says compass in there. Any ideas why the installation wasn't able to do it?

Also I should note that I'm using Windows 7 on a Mac via Parallels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@djthoms's response worked, but as it turns out I had ruby installed incorrectly as I did not check the box that said "create ruby in the PATH" (or something to that extent), which makes 'ruby' a recognizable command.

Again, during the installation process of ruby to windows, you must check a box in order for the installation to work correctly - **it is not already checked**.

Answer (score 26):

Make sure you have [ruby installed](http://rubyinstaller.org/) on your windows machine. Once that is done open Command Prompt with Ruby and type `gem install haml sass compass`
[image: CMD with Ruby]

Comment: Still no luck. I keep getting the same error. I should also note that I get the same error with java, even though the jre is definitely installed.

Answer (score 0):

@TravisHeeter
Once you have ruby + compass installed as above.  Make sure you exit the command prompt or in my case XYplorer from where I launching the "Git Bash" prompt and it was NOT pickup the PATH with ruby on it.  Hope it helps someone down the road.